# Is there a way to commit part of modified files (all files are staged) by using libgit2sharp?

Tags: git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

Is there a way to commit part of modified files (all files are staged) by using libgit2sharp?

There are no Commit method in Repository that takes path parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to commit part of modified files (all files are staged) by using libgit2sharp?

Currently, there's no way to perform a partial staging/unstaging in LibGit2Sharp. I'd suggest you to subscribe to **[Issue 195](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/195)** in order to be notified when this is available.

> There are no Commit method in Repository that takes path parameter.

Actually, the action of committing consists of taking a snapshot of the Index and creating a durable `Commit` git object in the object database. As such, the `Commit` API doesn't accept paths.

In order to create a `Commit` from a file (or list of files) on your file system, you'd first have to add them to the Index with `repo.Index.Stage()`, then invoke the `repo.Commit()` method.

Comment: Thanks. By control the Index property of repository, we can Unstage some files and commit the other part.